# Как распаковать ресурс, из приложения, в папку?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

Подскажите, каким образом можно распаковать ресурс в определенную папку?

Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, файл извлекся из приложения, с именем: **7za.exe**

Это консольный файл архиватора, который нужно распаковать по такому пути:

`C:\Program Files\7-Zip\` желательно `%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\`

Из за этого файла приходится создавать отдельный инсталятор для распаковки, как приложения, так и самого консольного файла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что антивирус скажет на это?

Comment: Никак. Ваше приложение, запущенное с юзеровскими правами, не должно хотеть писать в `%PROGRAMFILES%`. Инсталлировать имеет право только инсталлятор. Раньше, любой процесс имел право менять что угодно в системе, Windows была рассадником вирусов, слава богу, сейчас это не так.

Comment: @Vitokhv: Не удивительно, если пользователи будут оставлять отрицательные отзывы о вашем приложении.

Comment: @VladD есть сомнения по поводу твоей воспитанности, если ты знаешь какой код решит вопрос пользователя, зачем писать о том, что этого никак не сделать? Это противоречит поставленной задаче, и если есть какие либо ограничения, как их обойти, в моем вопросе не упоминалось.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько ссылок для размышления: [#1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19560/create-path-to-file-under-64-bit-programfiles-from-32-bit-process) [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365765/use-applicationdata-or-localapplicationdata-to-store-a-file-common-to-all-us) [#3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) [#4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275338/how-to-resolve-environment-variables-programatically-in-c-sharp-without-using-en)

Получилось таким способом:

```
    using System.IO;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Первый способ
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%") + @"\7-Zip\7za.exe", Properties.Resources._7za);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Второй способ
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%\\7-Zip\\7za.exe"), Properties.Resources._7za);
    }
```

Было бы не плохо разобраться как использовать такой код:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles)`

Чтобы указывать папку как переменную `CommonProgramFiles`