# Нужно добавить файл в программу

Tags: c#, файлы

Программа должна создавать файл формата `.html`. Нужно что-бы при этом в эту же папку из приложения распаковались `jquery.js, jquery-ui.js`. Я не могу понять как это реализовать. Какие есть идеи?

Comment: Что значит "правильно"? У вас есть какие-то способы на примете и вы не знаете, какой выбрать? (Озвучьте тогда способы и критерии правильности) Или "вообще без понятия" и можно советовать любой (скажем скопировать из папки dist два файла) способ?

Comment: Способов решить данную задачу - уйма! К примеру основные это: скачать из интернета, скопировать файл из определенной директории, скопировать файл из ресурсов, сгенерировать файл. Так что хотелось бы больше конкретики и посмотреть ваши попытки тоже было бы кстати...

Comment: "вообще без понятия"

Comment: открыл свойства проекта, вкладка ресурсы, кнопка "добавить ресурс" с типом "Файл" не работает

Comment: Знаете, давайте не будем делать резкие прыжки от "А" к "К", давайте постепенно: А -> Б -> В... Сначала вы сказали, что у вас нет идей. После этого надо озвучить какой-то алгоритм действий, а не бросаться открывать свойства проекта. У вас последний комментарий висит в воздухе - непонятно, какой вы путь выбрали. Озвучьте вашу идею, как сделать - тогда и будет понятно, что не работает. (Может вам вообще на ту вкладку не надо при выбранном способе). Дополните вопрос нажав "править", если у вас появилась конкретная идея и есть конкретная сложность реализации.

Comment: Итак, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку программа создала html файл, в нем записаны некие js скрипты, и ссылки на Jquery файлы которые должны быть в одной папке с данным html файлом. Эти Jquery файлы должны быть созданы в этой же папке. Вернее не созданы, а извлечены из ресурсов моей программы. Как это реализовать? Я дал достаточно информации?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распаковать ресурс, из приложения, в папку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664550/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 2):

Когда мы что либо добавляем в ресурсы, то мы автоматически получаем те данные, что находятся в этом файле. Если это изображение - получаем `Bitmap` или его аналоги, если текстовый файл - получаем `string`, если это файл - получим скорей всего `byte[]`. Зная тип мы смело можем воспользоваться классом `File` и записать нужные данные на диск.

Давайте простой пример:

- Жмем по проекту правой кнопкой мыши - свойства.
- Сбоку выбираем `Ресурсы`.
- В появившемся окне может писать, что нету ресурсов - смело тыкаем создать.
- Переносим на это окно мышью наш файл.
- Сбоку в меню свойств мы можем глянуть тип данного файла, там же мы можем сделать его простым набором байт (установив Binary)

[image: Property]

- Теперь мы можем работать с данным ресурсом так, как нам хочется. К примеру запишем всю информацию с файла на диск:

  ```
  File.WriteAllText("jquery-3.3.1.js", Properties.Resources.jquery_3_3_1);
  ```

Здесь мы вызываем обычный метод `WriteAllText()` который записывает весь string в файл. Если мы поставим в свойствах ресурса к примеру тип `Binary`, то мы также сможем записать файл, но уже другим методом (WriteAllBytes):

```
File.WriteAllBytes("jquery-3.3.1.js", Properties.Resources.jquery_3_3_1);
```

Если к примеру у нас изображение, то тут немного другой подход. Так, как наше изображение получает тип `Bitmap`, то мы можем сохранить это как байты, либо смело можем воспользоваться методом сохранения самого `Bitmap` (Save):

```
Properties.Resources.cha_elf.Save("img.png");
```

Как видите все зависит от типа данных, которые мы закладываем в ресурсы.
В общем удачи в изучении C#!